# Stucturing a WPF gauge control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, custom-controls, controltemplate

I have implemented a gauge control as a custom control in WPF. It is working very well, but I have hit an issue which is causing me to doubt whether it is structured it correctly.

Using different control templates, I can give the gauge radically different styles, for example like a speedometer, a voltmeter, a thermometer or an oil level.

The top level gauge control contains two collections, of Ranges and Pointers.

A Range defines a colored area on the scale. This is a simple object with a few properties.

A Pointer, fairly obviously, defines a pointer on the gauge. A guage can have multiple pointers, and the pointers can have differnt styles, for example a needle, a colored block or a slider (which the user can drag).

This is an example configuration:

```
<gauge:Gauge MinValue="0"
             MaxValue="350"
             MajorDivisions="7"
             MinorDivisions="5"
             Caption="Bar"
             Background="White"
             LabelOrientation="Horizontal"
             BorderThickness="3"
             StartAngle="-180"
             EndAngle="135"
             MinorTickMarkColor="Black"
             MajorTickMarkColor="Black"
             LabelsOnTicks="Even"
             LabelRadiusRelative="0.65"
             Template="{StaticResource DefaultRotaryGauge}" >
  <gauge:Gauge.Ranges>
    <gauge:Range MinValue="200"  MaxValue="350" Color="Green"/>
  </gauge:Gauge.Ranges>
  <gauge:Gauge.Pointers>
    <gauge:Pointer Position="{Binding Position1}" ShowNumericValue="Visible" Color="LightGray"/>
    <gauge:Pointer Position="{Binding Position2}" ShowNumericValue="Visible" Color="Red"/>
  </gauge:Gauge.Pointers>
  <gauge:Gauge.LabelStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
  </gauge:Gauge.LabelStyle>
</gauge:Gauge>
```

As shown above, the pointer position must work with binding, so it must be a dependency property and it must - as far as I understand - be in the visual tree.

For this purpose, the pointer class is defined as a control.

The control template for the gauge uses an ItemsControl to include the pointers. Each pointer has its own control template, but because there are different styes of pointer, I use a trigger to select one of several different templates for a pointer.

For example, my control template for a thermometer supports two pointer styles, which are selected as follows.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Pointers}"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource GridTemplate}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="local:Pointer">
      <Setter Property="Control.Template" Value="{StaticResource ThermometerPointer}"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="DisplayStyle" Value="Block">
          <Setter Property="Control.Template" Value="{StaticResource ThermometerBlock}"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

So far so good.

Now I have had a request, to change the colour of the liquid in the thermometer, when the value passes a given threshold. When I tried to implement this with a DataTrigger,

```
<gauge:Pointer Position="{Binding Position1}" DisplayStyle="Block">
  <gauge:Pointer.Style>
    <Style TargetType="gauge:Pointer">
      <Setter Property="Color" Value="Red"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
          <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GreaterThanConverter}">
              <Binding Path="Position1"/>
              <Binding Source="200.0"/>
            </MultiBinding>
          </DataTrigger.Binding>
          <Setter Property="Color" Value="Blue"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </gauge:Pointer.Style>
</gauge:Pointer>
```

the pointer stopped working entirely, because it lost the connection to its control template.

I was able to fix it by specifying the Control.Template in addition to the DataTrigger.

```
<gauge:Pointer Position="{Binding Position1}" DisplayStyle="Block">
  <gauge:Pointer.Style>
    <Style TargetType="gauge:Pointer">
      <Setter Property="Control.Template" Value="{StaticResource ThermometerBlock}"/>
      <Setter Property="Color" Value="Red"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
          <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GreaterThanConverter}">
              <Binding Path="Position1"/>
              <Binding Source="200.0"/>
            </MultiBinding>
          </DataTrigger.Binding>
          <Setter Property="Color" Value="Blue"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </gauge:Pointer.Style>
</gauge:Pointer>
```

This works, but I'm not happy with it. The user of the guage control cannot know this detail about the internal impolementation.

I think it is probably bad practice for the control template of the gauge control to define a Style for the pointer. My problem is I can't figure out another way to select different control templates for the pointer.

I thought that I might be able to select a control template using a converter (converting my DisplayStyle property to a ControlTemplate), but I can see where I would apply the convertor.

My only other idea is to get rid of the DisplayStyle property and instead define multiple pointer classes which derive from a common base pointer class. I could then define separate control templates for each derived pointer class.

I have several questions.

Firstly, am I doing this right? 
Does it even make sense to define the pointer as a control, with its own control template?

Secondly, is there a way to select the control template for the pointer, without requiring a style definition?

If not, is the idea with derived classes the way to go?